# parsing SimpleDateFormat to JodaTime

Tags: java, android, jodatime, simpledateformat

im creating a date from weeknumber, and a day of the week only. this I have successfully done with SimpleDateFormat, but i want to save it as jodatime, i have tried many things, but nothing that really worked.

This is my code so far.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week_of_year);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day_of_week);
sdf.format(cal.getTime());

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime jodatime = dtf.parseDateTime(sdf.toString());
```

I would like to get a jodatime så that my calendar kan sort objects based on the date, the time inst necessary.

When I run the code and want to display the jodatime, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "java.text.SimpleDateFormat@b93b42a0"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:945)
    at com.example.casper.autimeplan.Fragments.ScheduleFragment$MyJavaScriptInterface.getBasicInfo(ScheduleFragment.java:282)
    at com.example.casper.autimeplan.Fragments.ScheduleFragment$MyJavaScriptInterface.access$400(ScheduleFragment.java:186)
    at com.example.casper.autimeplan.Fragments.ScheduleFragment$MyJavaScriptInterface$1.run(ScheduleFragment.java:203)
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now().with( WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), weekOfYear )
               .with( WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), dayOfWeek )
```

## java.time

Do not use the troublesome old date-time classes. Also, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. For Android, see the ThreeTenABP project mentioned in last bullets below.

You have not defined what you mean by week number. There are many ways to define a week of year. I will assume you meant the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) definition of week # 1 having the first Thursday of the calendar, and Monday being the first day of every week.

Use the [`WeekFields`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/index.html) class, specifically the [`WeekFields.ISO`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/temporal/WeekFields.html#ISO) object.

```
long weekOfYear = 27 ; // 1-52 or 1-53 for ISO 8601 week-based years.
long dayOfWeek = 2 ;  // 1-7 for Monday-Sunday, per ISO 8601 standard.

LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
LocalDate adjusted = today.with( WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), weekOfYear )
                          .with( WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), dayOfWeek ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "2017-W27-02: " + adjusted ) ;
```

> 2017-W27-02: 2017-07-04

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/cfL2X0).

By the way… While not back-ported to older Android, other Java platforms can use the nifty [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library for this kind of work.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

You are simply passing toString of object which won't work.
try something like this

```
private static String parseDateTime(String input){
     String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
     DateTime dateTime  = DateTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern));
     return dateTime.toString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Read more [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)